# addEventListener is not a function even though array returns nodes?

Tags: javascript, html

I realize there are other questions with a similar title, but I'm running into something very strange.

In the code below I get an array of nodes and iterate through the array to add events:

```
   activateButtons = () => {
   let catButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('catalogItem')
   for(i in catButtons){
     console.log(catButtons[i])
     catButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
       catButtons[i].classList.toggle('active')
       if(catButtons[i].nextElementSibling){
         catButtons[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I get the same result whether I use ('click', e => or ('click', () =>. A later function uses ('click', () => and works just fine when a button is created.

I'm logging the array there to make sure that it's being captured (activateButtons is called after another function that constructs a dom element, that part works fine. In the log I get:

[image]

Based on other answers, I'm doing this correctly - I'm assigning event listeners to the nodes IN the array, not the array itself. The array is clearly being assembled. So why am I getting this error?

Elsewhere in the code, when a new button is initially created the function includes almost the exactly same code, except that I make the button (document.createElement) and then assign it immediately to the button, rather than requiring an array.

On load, the buttons already made are re-instantiated from a json file, and when I tried to addEventListener at that point, I didn't get the error, but also didn't get the event, so instead I decided to add the events all at once after the buttons are created. What am I missing here?

Comment: The logged `20` is what it tries to call `addEventListener` on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for..in` iterates over all enumerable properties anywhere in the prototype chain. For an HTMLCollection, this results in, *in addition* to numeric properties:

```js
for (const i in document.getElementsByClassName('catalogItem')) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

`length`, `item`, `namedItem` - the values on each of those properties are not elements (so calling `addEventListener` on them fails).

Use `for..of` instead, to invoke the HTMLCollection's iterator, which gives you *only* the elements:

```
for (const button of catButtons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // ...
  });
}
```

Since you're adding listeners in a loop, make sure to declare the iteration variable (`i` or `button`) - with `const`; using `for(i` results in there only being one global binding for `i`, which will result in problems if you find you want to examine the variable inside the listener. (See the [closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) question)

Comment: Well I can't accept an answer for the next nine minutes, but that did it. Thank you! In an older version of the function I was getting each element by individual ID based on a json index of buttons, and it just seemed like too much redundant code. Given how many other places this kind of thing needs to be done, you've saved me a ton of trouble down the line!